# Issue with creating a new DataFrame column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have an interesting problem that I can't seem to figure out. I have a DataFrame containing a bunch of DeliveryIDs and a separate list of Delivery IDs. The code I wrote to calculate a new column of boolean values looks like this:

```
df['col_new'] = df.DeliveryId.isin(delivery_list)
```

The code works in a Jupyter Notebook but when I place it into a python script it always returns 'False', despite a different result in Jupyter.

The function is :

```
def get_percent(df, delivery_list):
    df['col_new'] = df.DeliveryId.isin(delivery_list)
    pct = round((len(df[df.col_new == True])/len(df.col_new)) * 100, 1)
    print(f'% of Deliveries: {pct}%')
    return df
```

If I place a print(df.new_col.value_counts()) in the function to help debug I only receive False values.

I have arranged each function in its individual cell on Jupyter in the same order as my script, restarted the kernel and ran all the cells which gave me the correct output, but I'm not getting the same output when running my script.py file.

I believe there is some issue with the logic of calculating the values for the new column, perhaps due to Jupyter.

Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I was working on a virtual Windows 10 desktop with some kind of strange permissions. Once I ran the CLI with administrator privileges through the Anaconda3 navigator everything ran as expected.

For posterity's sake, if you have a similar issue, always try running the command prompt as an admin, or use Anaconda Navigator to open it up with the correct environment.